# Selecting item on list template using voice

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

How can I select the item on the list template using voice?

I can now select an item by tapping the screen on echo spot, then created an `ElementSelected` intent then provide some utterances like `{choice}`, `select {choice}`, `...`. and add the handler for that intent which will log some test string.

After the skill respond with the list, Alexa will no longer listen even though I set the `shouldEndSession` to `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to select the item on the list are:

- add `.listen` before emitting `:responseReady` to `this.response.listen('your reprompt speech here?`.
- add my list items to the `this.attributes`.
- add `choice` slot to the `ElementSelected` intent.

when the user says `select {choice} on the list`, Alexa will forward the `{choice}` slot to `ElementSelected` handler then I  do some further processing about the slot value.

Answer (score 0):

`shouldEndSession` must definitely be set to `false` if you want Alexa to listen further on.
https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-object

Comment: still, alexa stops listening when the list is rendered.

Comment: did you try to use your skill with the developer console test tool? It shows the actual response JSON body from you backend.

Comment: i use the actual echo spot. after adding the `.listen` to `this.response` Alexa was able to to listen further.

Answer (score 0):

I have returned SpeechletResponse from  **onIntent** like below code.

```
SpeechletResponse response = new SpeechletResponse();
response.setShouldEndSession(false);
response.setOutputSpeech(outputSpeech);
response.setReprompt(reprompt);
return response;
```